# How to "Restart" Android WiFi Hardware programmatically

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am attempting to develop an Android Application employing WiFi Direct/WiFi p2p.

I am experiencing all the usual issues associated with building such an application.

What I have noticed is that when I restart the set of devices I am testing with my application works fine (The First Time).

That is the initial connection status is `UNKNOWN/Ready to start data connection setup`.

What I am wondering is...

Is it possible to RESET the WiFi hardware of the Android device?
e.g. to toggle the power off then on again just for the WiFi hardware?

I know you can enable disable as follows:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(status);
```

However this disable/enable does not achieve the desired state.

Comment: I doubt you can do that without root

Comment: I was wondering about the factoryReset() methods associated with  android.net.ConnectivityManager, android.net.NetworkPolicyManager, 
android.net.wifi.WifiManager if something along those lines would work. however these reset methods clear data as well which I do not want to occur

Comment: @Zoe I have a rooted device, do you have steps or program snippet the restart the wi-fi  hardware programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use ifconfig command to do that
`ifconfig wlan0 down`

`ifconfig wlan0 up`

checked it on Nexus5 with android6.0